# CardLayout constraint works in Windows but not OS X

Tags: java, swing

As a preface: I know the code is rough — I just picked up Java this past week so I could make this thing cross platform for an experiment such that even my students would OS X machines could participate in a study.

So I've tested it on about 10 windows machines now with no problem, but on OS X, frame3 shows up with no panels at all (e.g. just a blank frame). I'm compiling on an OS X machine now and I see the following console output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout:     constraint must be a string
at java.awt.CardLayout.addLayoutComponent(CardLayout.java:190)
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1072)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:363)
at Reflexology1.<init>(Reflexology1.java:150)
at Reflexology1.main(Reflexology1.java:51)
```

The code is posted at http://pastebin.com/t3vqa0s6

Does anybody know what might be causing this problem under only OS X?

Comment: I would check the run-time version of Java.

Comment: Why would you set the layout to null?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JVM 6 only allows **non null** `String` constraints for `CardLayout`.

JVM 7 also allow `null`-value and replaces it by the emtpy `String` (`""`)

You are probably using one version on one platform and the other one on the other.

Answer (score 6):

My first guess is that the Windows and Macs machines are using different versions of the JDK. You can check this from the command line by running `javac -version` for the compiler and `java -version` for the runtime environment.